# iOS image with hidden hyperlinks

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've just been handed these requirements but wanted to check whats the best way to proceed with this?

There is a large Image file which needs to be displayed on an iPad which should be zoomable/pannable (thats the easy bit).

Now this image has several 'items' which need to be clickable - i.e. I need to generate a UIPopoverview with additional information about the item every time the item is clicked.

Whats the best way to go on about this?

TIA!

Comment: how about custom buttons with no background on top of the image?

Comment: The buttons would need to be relative to the image, i.e. if the image is zoomed in, the buttons would have to move relatively too. Not sure how that is possible?

Comment: One possibility would be to initialise a UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to the UIImageView. Then in the selector handle the popup based on the TapGesture's coordinates.

Comment: The Buttons is not a bad idea. If you configure all views correct (auto rezise subviews etc) then they should zoom and scroll along with the image. The buttons need to be subvies of the image though. Or they need to be subviews to the same content view of the same scroll view. (Depending on your view heirarchy) Another option, however, would be to catch the touches of the image and follow the links or what ever action is appropriate based on the coordinates in relation to the image and your "hotspots". For a beginner the buttons are easier to implement.

Comment: +1 for buttons. Just make sure you set auto-resize masks correctly.

Comment: Excellent. Button nested in the imageView did the trick! Thanks @HermannKlecker

Answer (score 0):

Button nested in the imageView did the trick! 
See previous post by @HermannKlecker